# creating a view / slicing of a numpy array, where conditional

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, slice

I have a numpy array containing data in the following format:

```
 print(trNp)

 [['9090648.0' '80789.886' '7.0' '41.72']
 ['10304517.0' '80789.886' '19.5' '4.12']
 ['32760.0' '77189.886' '3.2' '88.06']
 ['32760.0' '77189.886' '3.25' '22.74']
 .........

 ['17896415.0' '82589.886' '5.0' '23.92']
 ['17896415.0' '82589.886' '5.1' '6.0']
 ['17896415.0' '82589.886' '5.2' '10.08']
 ['12126325.0' '82589.886' '17.0' '2.38']
 ['12126325.0' '82589.886' '17.5' '2.28']]
```

i would like to be able to slice my array using conditional *like* the following.

```
a = '12126325.0'
z = 80000
t = (trNp[:,:1] == a) & (trNp[:,1:2] > z)

# create an array where 0th column is == to a and column 1 is == z
```

I then need to perform mathematical functions on the data in the remaining columns *like*:

```
m = np.mean(t[:,3:4])
```

to calculate the mean of the 'remaining' data in the 3rd column.

I feel like i am missing something simple but I can't seem to arrange this in anyway that makes sense/works.

Is it worth getting to grips with pandas?

I appreciate any help!

I should say also, the code above isn't right at all..  just for explaining the setup.

Comment: `trNp` has a string `dtype`, so the `>z` test doesn't work.  `t`, if it worked, would be a (n,1) boolean array.  `trNp[t]` would select rows from `trNp`.

Comment: i can create a seperate boolean array using `v = [trdNp[:,:1]==a]`  but am struggling with using that to parse the 'True' values and then combining it with the `> z`

Comment: Forget the `z` test for the moment.  Does `np.mean(trNp[  trNp[:,0]==a, :])` work for you?

Comment: Does this array have to have a string dtype?  Could you work with `x = trNp.astype(float)`?

Comment: i just got rid of the strings changes the np.appends where the values are being added to floats and now when i try print the trNp i get values like  [1.9056873e+07 9.1930785e+04 3.3500000e+00 1.5980000e+01]

Comment: also `np.mean(trNp[ trNp[:,0]==a, :])` is working, i think?

Comment: `==` tests with floats are tricky.  `np.isclose` matches within a tolerance.